# Superscript placement using unicode-math with scaling

Tags: luatex, superscripts, unicode-math

When I scale up a math font using the unicode-math package, the placement of
the superscript is too low. How can I globally adjust the placement of superscripts for this scaled math font?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Scale=1]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\[ \nu_e + \beta^+\]
\setmathfont[Scale=2.8]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\[ \nu_e + \beta^+\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The placement is low in luatex but raised as expected in xetex

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you scale the font inside the document or load it scaled to begin with.

Comment: Issue raised: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/287

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in `unicode-math-luatex`: if you try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Scale=2.8]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\[\nu_e + \beta^+\]

\end{document}
```

you get

[image: LuaTeX output]

with LuaLaTeX, while you get the expected

[image: XeTeX output]

with XeLaTeX.

If I add `\showthe\Umathsupshiftup\displaystyle` in the formula, I get `3.62994pt` with LuaLaTeX and `\showthe\fontdimen13\textfont2` gives `3.63pt` with XeLaTeX.

When I use `\showlists`, the box where the superscript is typeset is

```
.\hbox(11.42676+1.6268)x15.80873, shifted -3.62994, direction TLT
..\EU2/latinmodern-math.otf(0)/m/n/6.99997 +
```

with LuaLaTeX, while it is

```
.\hbox(11.42676+1.6268)x15.74875, shifted -10.16402
..\EU1/latinmodern-math.otf(0)/m/n/6.99997 glyph#12
```

with XeLaTeX. Since

```
10.16402/2.8 = 3.63001
```

the conclusion is that LuaLaTeX doesn't apply the scaling to the math font parameters,

Notice that this seems restricted to superscripts, because the box with the subscript is

```
.\hbox(8.66316+0.2156)x13.82913, shifted 5.22322, direction TLT
..\EU2/latinmodern-math.otf(0)/m/n/6.99997
```

in LuaLaTeX and

```
.\hbox(8.66316+0.2156)x13.76915, shifted 6.916
..\EU1/latinmodern-math.otf(0)/m/n/6.99997 glyph#1354
```

with XeLaTeX; still a difference, but much less noticeable (XeLaTeX seems wrong in this respect, because it seems to assume the presence of a superscript; the placement is the same if `\nu^{}_e` is used).

It doesn't seem to depend on the font, because the same problem shows with XITS Math or Asana Math.

If I use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Scale=2.8]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \Umathsupshiftup\displaystyle=10.16402pt                                  
}


\begin{document}

\[
\nu_e + \beta^+_{}
\]

\end{document}
```

the output is correct

[image]

Of course this is just a hack.

Comment: isn't that more of a comment than an  answer? (at least, it's same as my comment:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Trying to make a sense out of the parameters

Comment: Nice @egreg. One question: what does the command \check@mathfonts do?

Comment: @StevenGardiner It ensures the assignments of fonts to math groups is up-to-date with the current font size.

Comment: As of `unicode-math` v0.8m, the output is wrong with XeTeX, too.

Comment: @RuixiZhang Too bad! :-(

Comment: @RuixiZhang https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/287#issuecomment-456157803

Comment: @egreg I think I know where this goes wrong: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/287#issuecomment-456161175