# 'Dimension too large' error when \setmathfont has the option Scale=MatchLowercase

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, bugs

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
n $n \sqrt[n]{n}$
\end{document}
```

The above code when typeset with XeTeX produces an error saying 'Dimension too large'. Removing `[Scale=MatchLowercase]` resolves it but I need the option for the combination of other text and math fonts I'm using.

This issue seems recent. The last time I typeset a XeTeX document that uses `unicode-math` and contains `\sqrt[n]{n}` was about a year ago and the issue wasn't present at the time. Is there something wrong with [one of the latest versions](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/unicode-math) of `unicode-math`, namely 0.8m or 0.8n?

Nevertheless, the output PDF file is fine. I'm not sure if I should be worried, but having to keep dismissing the error is inconvenient. As a workaround I'll use the notation `^{1/n}` for now.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Add an issue at https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues (with lualatex it works, the problem is xetex specific).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

As of `unicode-math` v0.8o (2019/03/04), this bug is fixed for normal `Scale` usage. The update includes [a variant of Ulrike Fischer’s answer](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/commit/f14d5a46c94280b030d247ed8bff3b1426221685), and more crucially, [a sloppier setup for font dimensions in fam 2 and 3](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/commit/179222bf2f46fb90d120342d4910d2ad5467193b).

The change from `ScaleAgain = 1.00001` and `ScaleAgain = 0.99999` to `ScaleAgain = 1.0001` and `ScaleAgain = 0.9999` effectively *lowered* the upper bound of the set *B* in Theorem 1 below. The set *B* now terminates at around `k=10000`, which is around `Scale=0.153`. This means, as long as the user requested `Scale` is *above* 0.153, then `unicode-math` would setup font dimensions correctly.

If the requested `Scale` is below 0.153, then the font dimension problem persists. But it was deemed that normal usage would never produce `Scale=0.153` or lower, so we are safe for the most parts. See more detailed analysis [here](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/515#issuecomment-466217619) and [here](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/517#issue-413540887).

---

### Old answers

Although I agree with Ulrike Fischer that this is a `unicode-math` bug, I’m afraid that I have to disagree with the claim that “`\__um_fontdimen_to_percent:nN` is broken”. Indeed, using `\dim_to_decimal_in_sp:n` is a great improvement, but it is *not* where the actual problem lies. I shall first present my solution and then try to discuss the root cause.

Note that the following solution is meant to be temporary until `unicode-math` fixes this in the next release.

---

### Solution

For a relatively simple solution, you can use the new feature `ScaleAgain` to slightly distort the font size (it won’t be visible to the human eyes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}% v0.8n, 2019/02/15
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,ScaleAgain=0.99999]{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
n $n \sqrt[n]{n}$
\end{document}
```

[image: ScaleAgain]

In practice, you’ll have to try a range of `ScaleAgain` near 1 to be able to compile. Again, this shall be fixed in the next release of `unicode-math`.

---

### A Theorem on the overflow behavior of `unicode-math` v0.8n

For those who are interested in the bizarre overflow behavior, here is a theorem, based on the two fixed `ScaleAgain` factors in `unicode-math` v0.8n.

First comes the visualizations on which `Scale`’s are safe and which may cause problem:

> Near `Scale=1`:
>   [image: scale1]
>   Near `Scale=1.2`:
>   [image: scale1.2]
>   Near `Scale=1.5`:
>   [image: scale1.5]
>
> All *green* line segments represent the safe `Scale` factors, while *red* line segments represent the problematic ones.
>
> Here is the rigorous mathematical description:
>   [image: Theorem]
>
> In particular, `Scale=1.031369386`, `Scale=1.031374755`, `Scale=1.031384644` and `Scale=1.031390014` *all lead to* `! Dimension too large`. Near `Scale=1.03138`:
>   [image: scale1.03138]

---

### Discussions

The x-heights of Georgia and Cambria Math are, respectively, `986/2048` and `956/2048`. And `Scale=MatchLowercase` is correctly converted into `Scale=1.03138` by `fontspec`. Now, if we were to apply the [suggested re-definition of `\__um_fontdimen_to_percent:nN`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475802) when using Latin Modern Math, we would be surprise to find out that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}% v0.8n, 2019/02/15
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475802, by Ulrike Fischer:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nn \__um_fontdimen_to_percent:nN
  {
    \fp_eval:n { \dim_to_decimal_in_sp:n { \fontdimen #1 #2 } / 100 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\tempscale{1.03138}% Also fails at 1.02, 1.05, 1.07
\setmathfont[Scale=\tempscale]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}
n $n \sqrt[n]{n}$
\end{document}
```

still produces the `! Dimension too large.` error.

Even more strangely, if we instead use a scale factor of either `1.03137` or `1.03139`, then your Georgia + Cambria Math example compiles successfully, and so does my Latin Modern Math example (with or without the re-definition of `\__um_fontdimen_to_percent:nN`).

The root cause of the problem is the new feature `ScaleAgain` from `fontspec`, which is meant to solve a long standing problem (see [Superscript placement using unicode-math with scaling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232320) and [Scale option doesn't fully work with LuaLaTeX](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/287)). Oh, and also the fact that TeX is “not good at math”.

To setup the math-related legacy font dimensions correctly, `unicode-math` must load the same math font *three times*. But TeX wouldn’t allow the same font to be loaded twice at the same size, so `unicode-math` has to load the font at slightly different sizes for the 2nd and the 3rd times. These slightly different sizes are obtained by *compounding* the previous scale factor. This was the main reason that `ScaleAgain` was introduced in `fontspec`, so `unicode-math` can do `ScaleAgain=1.00001` for the 2nd time and `ScaleAgain=0.99999` for the 3rd time. As [my comment](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/287#issuecomment-457846112) pointed out, sometimes `unicode-math` will fail to distinguish the three sizes due to TeX’s binary arithmetic.

Your example was “unlucky” enough to have `Scale=1.03138`, which translates to `Round( 1.03138 * 2^16 ) = 67593`. After `ScaleAgain=1.00001`, TeX sees `1.03139`, which translates to `Round( 1.03139 * 2^16 ) = 67593`. So TeX thinks that the second family and the first family are the same font, and proceeds to overwrite fontdimen’s under the instruction of `unicode-math`. This causes the overflow, because the new fontdimen’s are no longer percentages which are less than one, but are now physical lengths which can get quite large.

With `\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,ScaleAgain=0.99999]{Cambria Math}`, we are basically trying to prevent TeX from loading the math font at the same size accidentally.

Comment: `\__um_fontdimen_to_percent:nN` is broken. Multiplying a dimension by 65536 is simply a very bad  idea - it will overflow even if the dimension is only 1pt large. Imho your ScaleAgain workaround is only hiding the problem - something in the math is wrong when unicode-math is trying to insert a kern.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I fully agree with your improvement for `\__um_fontdimen_to_percent:nN`. But, on the contrary, your `\dim_to_decimal_in_sp:n` actually hides the bug even more IMHO. See, `\setmathfont[Scale=0.7]{latinmodern-math.otf}` is *not* supposed to work, either, but your improvement let it through. I continued my discussion [here](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/515#issuecomment-466076482).

Comment: My compliments: many details and very nice.

Answer (score 8):

Imho the definition of `\__um_fontdimen_to_percent:nN` is faulty, it should use `\dim_to_decimal_in_sp` instead of `\dim_to_decimal:n`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nn \__um_fontdimen_to_percent:nN
  {
    \fp_eval:n { \dim_to_decimal_in_sp:n {  \fontdimen #1 #2 } / 100 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
n $n \sqrt[n]{n}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll leave it to you to add an issue to [github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues) along with the suggested fix.

Comment: No, you found the bug so you should add the issue. I already spent enough time in finding the relevant code piece.

Comment: OK. Done: [github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/515](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/515)

Comment: For information : this is not XeTeX-specific ; also arise with LuaLaTeX (only with beamer, in my setup) and the above does fix it.

Comment: @ysalmon yes the erronous definition is in the style of both engines and it is quite probable that lualatex has failures to, but the specific example here fails only with xelatex.

Comment: Errr… the `65536` was previously moved from the outside to the inside to fix something else in [my comment to another issue](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/478#issuecomment-446607874). I never saw this could lead to overflow so easily…

Comment: Oh dear! This posted solution is not bullet-proof: It still breaks down if I use `\setmathfont[Scale=1.031380753]{latinmodern-math.otf}`. See the [continued discussions](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/515#issuecomment-465792368) on GitHub.