# NFSS: Can I scale fonts using fractions (more accurate) instead of decimals?

Tags: fonts, scaling, calculations

I would like to be able to pass a fraction expression to `s*[<number>]` in a `\DeclareFontShape`. The ultimate goal is to instruct LaTeX2e’s New Font Selection Scheme (NFSS) to perform more accurate calculations. Can this be done?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}[
  Scale=1.10502958579881657 % 747/676
]
\setsansfont{texgyreheros-regular.otf}[
  Scale=1.00685871056241427 % 734/729
]
\begin{document}
\fontsize{10.5bp}{15.75bp}\selectfont
By NFSS: \the\numexpr\fontdimen6\font\relax\par
What I want: \the\numexpr\dimexpr10.5bp*747/676\relax\relax\par
\sffamily
By NFSS: \the\numexpr\fontdimen6\font\relax\par
What I want: \the\numexpr\dimexpr10.5bp*734/729\relax\relax
\end{document}
```

> [image: scale1]
>   In my actual document, I am mixing Latin fonts with CJK fonts, hence a variety of scaling factors is needed… I dislike the rounding errors as large as `5sp`…

---

**Background information** for those who are unfamiliar with TeX’s binary arithmetic. In the following example, I try to magnify the original dimension by `1.2`. When `1.2\mydimen` is encountered, TeX first converts the floating number `1.2` into its internal integer representation: `Round(1.2*65536) = Round(78643.2) = 78643`. The after-rounding result is then multiplied to `1,000,000sp` producing `Floor(78643*1,000,000/2^16) = Floor(1199996.9482421875) = 1,199,996sp`.

But if we rewrite `1.2` as `6/5` and then use primitives `\multiply` and `\divide`, or use eTeX’s expression extension, we can get more accurate results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newdimen\mydimen
\newcommand*\onemillionsp{15.2587890625pt\relax}
\begin{document}
\mydimen\onemillionsp
\verb|\mydimen|: \the\numexpr\mydimen\relax\par
\mydimen1.2\mydimen
\verb|1.2\mydimen|: \the\numexpr\mydimen\relax\par
\smallskip

Use \verb|\multiply| and \verb|\divide| primitives:\par
\mydimen\onemillionsp
\multiply\mydimen by 6\divide\mydimen by 5\relax
\verb|\mydimen * 6 / 5|: \the\numexpr\mydimen\relax\par
\smallskip

Use eTeX's extension:\par
\mydimen\onemillionsp
\verb|\<expression>|: \the\numexpr\mydimen*6/5\relax
\end{document}
```

> [image: scale2]

Comment: You're free to dislike a difference of 5 scaled points, which is less than 0.000027mm=27nm, which falls low in the range of ultraviolet light (10nm–400nm). The font scaling operations use `<factor><dimen>`, so they're intrinsically less accurate than using `\multiply` or `\divide`, but for font sizes the accuracy is in the order of at most tens of scaled points, very far from the wavelength of visible light.

Comment: @egreg Precisely. But this seemingly harmless rounding error is the fundamental cause for [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475792) a while back. Under NFSS with `<factor><dimen>`, TeX cannot tell the difference between `1.03138` and `1.03138*1.00001≈1.03139` (even though LaTeX3 is well-equipped with such calculations). Were fraction expressions allowed, it would improve very little for the human eyes but much more from an implementation perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to hack into NFSS after all. Should anyone from the LaTeX3 team be interested, please feel free to implement this enhanced version `:)`.

> [image: fraction]

My new implementation to `\empty@sfcnt` is compatible with decimal expressions. The fraction expression syntax, however, requires eTeX’s `\dimexpr`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Look ahead for either a decimal or a fraction
%   and extract all stuff after the first slash:
\def\detect@decimal@or@frac#1/#2\detect@decimal@or@frac{%
  \edef\@tempa{#2}%
}
% Hack into NFSS:
\def\empty@sfcnt#1{%
      \@tempdimb \f@size\p@
      \ifx\optional@arg\@empty
      \else
% The following line was the original:
%        \@tempdimb \optional@arg\@tempdimb
% Replaced with my new implementation:
        \expandafter\detect@decimal@or@frac
          \optional@arg/0\detect@decimal@or@frac
        \def\@tempb{0}%
        \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
          % A decimal or an integer is passed here
          \@tempdimb \optional@arg\@tempdimb
        \else
          % A fraction is passed here
          \@tempdimb \dimexpr\@tempdimb*\optional@arg\relax
        \fi
% End of new implementation
        #1{Font\space shape\space `\curr@fontshape'\space
           will\space be\MessageBreak
           scaled\space to\space size\space \the\@tempdimb}%
      \fi
      \edef\external@font{\mandatory@arg\space at\the\@tempdimb}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand\test[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \texttt{\string\fontspec\{texgyretermes-regular.otf\}[Scale=\{#1\}]}:\\
  \fontspec{texgyretermes-regular.otf}[Scale={#1}]%
  \the\fontdimen6\font\par
  \medskip
  \endgroup
}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\test{1}
\test{1.2}
\test{6/5}
\test{1,4}
\test{14/10}
\test{1.105029585798816568}% 747/676
\test{747/676}
\end{document}
```